# Task scheduled with Hangfire doesn't get triggered in .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, hangfire

I'm trying to implement triggering of method in my `console application with Hangfire`.

This is how my `Program class` looks like:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static IServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.ConfigureDI();

        program.InitializeScheduledJob("* * * * *");
    }

    private void ConfigureDI()
    {
        var configuration = GetConfiguration();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);

        services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();

        Provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true);

        return configurationBuilder.Build();
    }

    private void InitializeScheduledJob(string cron)
    {
        var testService = Provider.GetService<ITestService>();
        var configuration = Provider.GetService<IConfiguration>();

        var scheduledJobId = configuration.GetSection("ScheduledJobId");
        var hangfireConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:HangfireConnection");

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UsePostgreSqlStorage(hangfireConnectionString.Value, new PostgreSqlStorageOptions { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) });

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(scheduledJobId.Value, () => testService.TestMethodAsync(), cron);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I use DI in the application and I'm trying to invoke the `TestMethodAsync` method in `TestService` service, but despite adding it as recurring job, it never gets invoked.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Problem statement can be refined to only provide the **non-working** part of the code, At broad level code looks fine, but this can have issue, if values at run-time are not correctly fetched. 
1. What's there in the method `TestMethodAsync()`, 
2. Does a simple sample without DI works. 
3. You are passing a `Func<Task>` as parameter, how is that executed
To my understanding here there would be a requirement to execute the `Task`, that's what you would be missing and hence no method execution

Comment: @MrinalKamboj sample without DI works, so it must be some issue with DI

Comment: Please provide the code which works, idea here is debug and figure out what is filled in when you call `Provider.GetService<ITestService>()` is its not `TestService`, then it would be null, debugging the DI framework and understanding the issue shall not be complex